# cv2.estimateRigidTransform with fullAffine=False

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, affinetransform

According to [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#estimaterigidtransform) `cv2.estimateRigidTransform` have parameter `fullAffine`:

> fullAffine – If true, the function finds an optimal affine
>   transformation with no additional restrictions (6 degrees of freedom).
>   Otherwise, the class of transformations to choose from is limited to
>   combinations of translation, rotation, and uniform scaling (5 degrees
>   of freedom).

I don't understand what is meant by 5 degrees of freedom, as I understand translation, rotation, and uniform scaling can be done with 4 variables (some more info here http://nghiaho.com/?p=2208)

1. By `uniform scaling` they mean that x and y scale will be the same?

I have tried

```
print('cv2.__version__', cv2.__version__)
m = cv2.estimateRigidTransform(_prev_pts, _curr_pts, fullAffine=False)
print('m.shape', m.shape)
print('m',m)
```

Output:

```
cv2.__version__ 3.4.3
m.shape (2, 3)
m [[ 1.00165841e+00 -2.10742695e-04  4.28874117e+00]
 [ 2.10742695e-04  1.00165841e+00  1.23242652e+00]]
```

Output looks like stated in documentation(4 unique values):

[image]

2. Another question is how to decompose matrix `m` to rotation, scaling and translation matrices, i.e. `m = R*T*S`?

Comment: I too think it should be only 4 dof. Decomposition dhould be: angle = asin(a12), scale=a11/cos(angle) and translation = (b1,b2) not sure whether angle is missing a factor -1 though...

Comment: Actually in code there is `4 degrees of freedom` https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/1913482cf5d257d7da292bb2c15f22d0588d34dc/modules/video/src/lkpyramid.cpp#L1503 https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/96bf26611e5c512ce39a5ac302fd2a132b7d1df4/modules/video/include/opencv2/video/tracking.hpp#L242 , so this is a mistake in documentation.